# Terminal : Difference between quoted argument and non quoted in find function

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, find, quotes

What is the difference between these two commands in the command line in the terminal on ubuntu?

`find . -name "*.txt"`

`find . -name *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the shell you are using and the contents of your directory.

If you're unfortunate enough to use csh (or some of its heritage, like zsh) for some reason, it will refuse to execute this when there is no file in your directory that matches the pattern (unless you've turned that behaviour off).

If there are files that match the pattern, the command will be expanded by the shell:

```
find . -name foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt
```

and `find` will report a syntax error. Unless there is a single file that matches, then you get:

```
find . -name foo.txt
```

and this will then only find files named "foo.txt" in subdirectories.

Only if you're using a sane shell **and** there are no files matching in the current directory will the two commands be identical.

Moral: don't do it. Always use quotes.

Comment: Just a note: `zsh` also behaves like `csh` in this regard, but you can at least turn it off with `setopt NONOMATCH`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, will add this to answer